# Doubly linked list delete last C

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

Im working on a implementation of a doubly linked list.  I want the linked list to be limited by some length.  When the list becomes longer then delete the last node.  Im having some problems here. I want to define tail so that i dont have to search for the end.  Here is the implementation i am working on it will allow for a length of 4 then start deleting the last node.

```
/* Doubly Linked List implementation */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Node  {
    char command[1024];
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};

struct Node* head; //global pointing to head
struct Node* tail; //global pointing to tail

//Creates a new Node and returns pointer to it. 
struct Node* GetNewNode(char *line) {
    struct Node* newCommand = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        int i = 0;
        while(line[i] != '\0'){
            newCommand->command[i] = line[i];
            i++;
        }
        newCommand->prev = NULL;
    newCommand->next = NULL;
    return newCommand;
}

//Inserts a Node at head of doubly linked list
void InsertAtHead(char *line) {
    struct Node* newCommand = GetNewNode(line);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = newCommand;
        tail = newCommand;
        return;
    }
    head->prev = newCommand;
    newCommand->next = head; 
    head = newCommand;
}
//Use tail to delete the last node
void deleteLast(){
    struct Node* temp = tail;
    tail = temp->prev;
    free(tail->next);
    tail->next = NULL;
}
//Print in reverse orer
void Print() {
    struct Node* temp = tail;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%s \n",temp->command);
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
}

int main() {

        int numNodes = 0;
        char line[1024];
        head = NULL; 
        tail = NULL; // empty list. set head/tail as NULL. 
        printf("next node: ");
        while (fgets(line, 1024, stdin)) {
            line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
            if(numNodes == 4){
                numNodes -= 1;
                deleteLast();
            }
            InsertAtHead(line);Print();
            numNodes += 1;
            printf("next node: ");
        }
        Print();
}
```

it seems to be deleting the last node but printing some weird symbols after.  Im guessing that its a problem with how i free() but i cant figure it out.
note some of this code is taken from https://gist.github.com/mycodeschool/7429492

Comment: what do you mean by printing some weird symbols after? what symbols?

Comment: for instance if i input: 1,2,3,4,5,6 the last print looks like this, 3,4,5LI�                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
6LI�

Comment: @kaylum i think that they do stay as null for the first node added but after that ->prev will be set for head which also means tail. after that only head will be changed until deleteLast. i might not understand what is happening though.

Comment: Just a thought, as you learn about linked-lists, know there are several types of linked-lists. The Head/Tail list as you have (with several approaches) and a Circular list. A circular list does not have Head/Tail sudo-nodes, the last node always points back to the first, and vice-versa in a doubly-linked list. Each type has advantages/disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, hoewever, there is an error in copying the command to the node:

```
    while(line[i] != '\0'){
        newCommand->command[i] = line[i];
        i++;
    }
```

should be:

```
    while(line[i] != '\0'){
        newCommand->command[i] = line[i];
        i++;
    }
    newCommand->command[i] = '\0';
```

(You forgot to terminate the copied command.)

Note also that you must check not to go beyond available space, e.g.:

```
    while(i<1023 && line[i] != '\0'){
        newCommand->command[i] = line[i];
        i++;
    }
    newCommand->command[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: also fixed the printing bug!